# How can I move the first five files in a directory to a new directory?

Tags: unix, rust, mv

I am trying to replicate the bash command `` mv `ls | head -5` ./subfolder1/ `` in Rust.

This is meant to move the first five files in a directory and it works fine in the shell. I am using the `Command` process builder but the following code fails at runtime:

```
Command::new("mv")
    .current_dir("newdir")
    .args(&["`ls | head -5`", "newdir"])
    .env("PATH", "/bin")
    .spawn()
```

Output:

```
mv:  cannot stat cannot stat '`ls | head -5`': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with pretty much all such structures, `Command` is a frontend to `fork` followed by the `exec*` family, meaning it executes *one* command, it's not a subshell, and it does not delegate to a shell.

If you want to chain multiple commands you will have to run them individually and wire them by hand, though [there exist libraries to provide a shell-style interface](https://crates.io/crates/duct_sh) (with the danger and inefficiencies that implies).

Can't rightly see why you'd bother here though, all of this seems reasonably easy to do with [`std::fs`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/index.html) (and possibly a smattering of [`std::env`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/index.html)) e.g.

```rust
for entry in fs::read_dir(".")?.take(5) {
    let entry = entry?;
    fs::rename(entry.path(), dest.join(entry.file_name()))?;
}
```

Comment: Note that `ls` gives files in alphabetical order, but the [`read_dir` docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_dir.html) state: "_The order in which this iterator returns entries is platform and filesystem dependent._"